# How to fix Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview, xcode11.4

I have a problem with the Users Location.

When im trying to build the program it gets this error code: (Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value)

My code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
   


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configerLocationServices()
    }
    
    private func configerLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: locationManager)
        }
    }
    
    private func beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true //<--- the problem is here
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    private func zoomToLastestLocation(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        mapView.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did get latest Location")
        
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else { return }
        
        if currentCoordinate == nil {
            zoomToLastestLocation(with: latestLocation.coordinate)
        }
            
        currentCoordinate = latestLocation.coordinate
        
    }
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("The Status changed")
        if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            self.beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: manager)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what im doing wrong, has anyone the solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A likely cause is that `mapView = nil` because the outlet is not connected correctly in the Storyboard. That is one of the explanations in https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/1187415.

Comment: Try adding configerLocationServices() in viewDidAppear() method and not in viewDidLoad()

Comment: That didn't helped :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 private func setNewLoaction(lat:CLLocationDegrees,long:CLLocationDegrees,markerTitle:String){
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 15)
        self.googleMapsView?.camera = camera
        self.googleMapsView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: center)
        marker.map = self.googleMapsView
        marker.title = markerTitle
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
    
    //MARK:- MAP VIEW
    
    private func setUpMap(){
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width-30, height: self.mapView.frame.height))
        self.googleMapsView?.settings.compassButton = true
        self.googleMapsView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.googleMapsView?.settings.myLocationButton = true
        self.mapView.addSubview(self.googleMapsView!)
    }
```

I have called setUpMap in ViewDidload and this setLoaction function in GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate =:

```
  func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    
            
            destinationField.text = place.formattedAddress
            destinationLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
            destinationLongitutude = place.coordinate.longitude
            setNewLoaction(lat:  destinationLatitude!, long: destinationLongitutude!, markerTitle: "Destination Location")
            
       
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

you can call this anywhere as per you need, do remember to turn on location when asked for permission and if using in simlulator go to Features/Loaction/custom Location

Comment: I still don't get it :(

Comment: @BlueDynamixs if you can share  your class with me I will be ready to help

Comment: Its okay I just followed an other tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

I have now an other code for the same thing it is shorter than the old one.

Here is the code:

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true // <--- Crash
    }
```

}

And now it gets the same problem as the old one :(